# How can I depend on a parent target from a nested ant project?

Tags: ant

Given a build.xml file:

```
<project name="main" default="build">

<target name="main.init"/>
<extension-point name="init.tasks" depends="main.init"/>
<target name="init" depends="init.tasks"/>

<extension-point name="build.tasks" depends="init"/>
<target name="build" depends="build.tasks"/>

<include file="subsystem1.xml"/>
<include file="subsystem2.xml"/>
</project>
```

And a subsystemX.xml with something like:

```
<project name="subsystemX">
<task name="init" extensionOf="init.tasks"/>
<task name="build" depends="init" extensionOf="build.tasks"/>
</project>
```

I can now say `ant build` and all subsystems will go through `init` and `build` as expected.

However I would also like to be able to say `ant subsystem.build` and build only that subsystem. The problem is that each subsystem's `build` depends on all other subsystems' `init`. In this case however only the `subsystem.init` will be executed, as ant just looks at `subsystem.build`'s dependencies.

Ideally I would like to add the main `init` as a dependency to each subsystem's `build` task, but `include` blindly prepends "subsystem." to every task name and depends entry so that I don't seem to be able to reference anything outside.

**How can I make `subsystem.build` depend on the main `init` task?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a workaround:

In build.xml, I add additional targets for each included file:

```
<target name="subsystem1.global.init" depends="main.init"/>
<target name="subsystem1.all.init" depends="init"/>
<include file="subsystem1.xml" as="subsystem1"/>

<target name="subststem2.global.init" depends="main.init"/>
<target name="subsystem2.all.init" depends="init"/>
<include file="subsystem2.xml" as="subsystem2"/>
```

Then in subsystemX.xml, I can depend on "global.init" and "all.init", e.g.

```
<project name="subsystemX">
<task name="init" depends="global.init" extensionOf="init.tasks" />
<task name="build" depends="init, all.init" extensionOf="build.tasks"/>
</project>
```

As you can see this does not scale well and I'm still hoping to find a better solution.